# Does my fish look like she is ready to drop her fry?

Tags: fish, breeding

[image][image]
I know she is prego but I don’t know when she will drop her fry help

Comment: it is not easy to tell,it depends on how many babies there is she might get them today or it might be a couple of weeks.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) I've closed your question as a duplicate. Please check it out for the answer to your question.